Missing file during ng build
While running an ng build in my Angular project, I get this error message:
[DEBUG] Failed to read directory "/Users/michael/Dev/versicherungrepository1/vp-1-frontend/angular:script/global:scripts": open /Users/michael/Dev/versicherungrepository1/vp-1-frontend/angular:script: no such file or directory
Can anyone tell me which file or folder this might be? I've been looking for a solution for three days with ChatGPT and just can't find one.

Various libraries temporarily deactivated
angular.json searched
.env checked



"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "/dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/my-theme.scss",
              "src/tailwind.css",
              "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
              
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "3mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },



One more addition, the error appears regardless of whether I run it on my local system, my Raspberry Pi or on my virtual server. It is simply skipped on the first two, but the virtual server has considerably less power. Therefore, the process is not continued there.

Can you update your question to include the "build" object in your angular.json file?

I have found the error. It was in the script ‘node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js’
I have now completely removed swiper from my project. Now everything works again.
